# Having issues with an If statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have been having issues with this if statement. I am trying to highlight a range and say if it is greater than a certain number, then I switch the number format. Here is my code

wSD2 is my worksheet. I have only done an if statement for the first range

```
With WSD2

    If Range(("B3"), ("E" & .Rows.Count)) > 10000 Then
    .Range(.Range("B2"), .Range("E" & .Rows.Count)).Select
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0,000"
    End If

   .Range(.Range("H2"), .Range("J" & .Rows.Count)).Select
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0,000"

    .Range(.Range("F2"), .Range("G" & .Rows.Count)).Select
    Selection.Style = "Percent"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
End With
```

If the number in that range is not greater than 10000, then it should not touch the number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

G

Comment: Also your first `If` statement doesn't refer to the `With` statement. Add the `.` to "anchor" the range to `WSD2`.

Comment: You cannot use operends like `>` on a range of values, you will need to loop and test one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check each cell in that range, I assume. Also you should work directly with the data instead of using `.Select`:

```
With WSD2
    For Each cel In .Range(.Range("B3"), .Range("E" & .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row))
        If cel.Value > 10000 Then
            cel.Style = "Comma"
            cel.NumberFormat = "0,000"
        End If
    Next cel
...
End With
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly. Thanks!